# MySQL how are indexes used in this example?

Tags: mysql

This is probably in the MySQL documentation, but I have not been able to find it. So I know that if I'm selecting a record from a database, the fastest results are when the fields I'm selecting and the fields in the WHERE clause are parts of an index. Say that I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE b=X AND c=Y
```

What key or combination of keys would give me the fastest result?

Option 1: one key that's (a, b, c).

Option 2: one key that's (b, c) because those are in the where statement.

Option 3: one key that's (b, c, a) because b and c are in the where statement, and a is the value that ultimately needs to be looked up. (Seems logical to me, but I have no idea if this makes any MySQL sense...)

Options 4: two keys, one that's (b, c) and one that is just (a).

Sorry, I'm a really MySQL newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case a composite index on `(b,c)` should do the job. You do not need an index on `a` since it is not in your `WHERE` clause. Its presence in the `SELECT` list doesn't affect how the rest of the query has to be indexed.

You could also use `(b,c,a)` *in that order* since MySQL will use column combinations in composite indexes starting from left to right. That isn't necessary for this use case but could future-proof your code if you ever did need to query all three columns  Indexing `(a,b,c)` would *not* work in this query for that reason.

```
WHERE b='X' AND c='Y' AND z='Z'
```

From [the MySQL docs on index usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

As always, when in doubt, check the query's execution plan after creating your index to verify that it can be used as intended.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE b='X' AND c='Y'
```

Comment: In some RDBMS, indexing on (b,c,a) would be slightly faster for this very specific use case (with the trade-off being larger index size) because the query engine has all the data it needs to satisfy the query by looking at the index alone and wouldn't have to read the actual table at all.  In other words, 'a' is in the index so why read from the table?  In most cases that's probably a premature optimization though.

Comment: Joe, which RDBMS would these be? I have an InnoDB table with about 42,000 records and both the (b,c) and (b,c,a) indices take the same amount of time -- 20 ms -- which I think is a little excessive for a relatively small table like this one.

Comment: I couldn't find anything definitive that says whether or not MySQL uses the optimization I describe.  I'm pretty sure it does, but didn't want to mislead you so I left it a generic comment.  That said, it's probably not going to make a noticeable difference on such a small table. It's hard to say what would cause it to be slower than you expect without having a lot more details about your setup.

Comment: Agreed - and I would add that 20ms on 42k records doesn't seem that bad to me. The query time won't likely scale lineraly with the growth of the rowset.